# How do you organize messages to be translated in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, localization, internationalization

Please note i am not talking about the .abr files.

I have been following several tutorials on internationalization in Flutter using the intl package. I noticed that they always use a single AppLocalization class for storing all the messages that will be used in the application. Since it was a tutorial, I am wondering if we will always have to do it that way. I mean in a real application we will probably have hundreds messages to maintain. It would be a mess to put them all in a single class.

Maybe we should have a localization class for each Page?

What are your suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Flutter Intl package it's the right solution; also i used to [Easy Localization](https://pub.dev/packages/easy_localization).
This package has a "[inherited widget](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/InheritedWidget-class.html) " concept, so if you want to change automatically change UI for changed Local Language, it will be quite useful to you.

> Maybe you want to localization JSON update to server and use application new key-value without deploy store. EasyLocalzation does read the server-side JSON file.